# How can I plot implicit equations?

Tags: plotting, faq

If you enter the following into Wolfram | Alpha, you get nice graphs:

```
graph 4 x^4 + y^2 = 2
```

[image]

How do you do this in *Mathmatica*? I realize that these are not functions, because the graphs do not pass the straight line test. But what does Wolfram Alpha do to put these things into something that *Mathematica* can understand?

Comment: Welcome, Rollie, to Mathematica SE. Please don't be put off by the down votes you received.  I realize that you just joined the web site today. When you examine the posted questions, you'll quickly get a sense of the sorts of issues typically raised. Generally speaking, you'll be expected to post a question that you have researched about on this site and in the Mathematica documentation. Furthermore, it's a good idea to show what you've already tried (including Mathematica code) and the results you got.

Comment: There's a great example here: http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2008/May/msg00021.html

Answer (score 44):

In v8, you can type input

```
= graph 4 x^4 + y^2 = 2
```

The first equal sign tells Mathematica to query WolframAlpha. The result is the command

```
ContourPlot[4*x^4 + y^2 == 2, {x, -1.1, 1.1}, {y, -1.8, 1.8}]
```

followed by the plot.

Comment: This answer is especially useful in pointing to how one can get WolframAlpha to show the corresponding *Mathematica* input.

Comment: In recent years, Wolfram|Alpha will have a "Show Code" option under many of its outputs.

Answer (score 28):

The forms you wish to plot are called implicit equations. Type "implicit equation" into the search input field of the *Mathematica* Documentation Center. The second hit will be `ContourPlot`. On that documentation page, under Applications, you will find the following, which tells you everything you need to know about making the kind of plots you want.

[image: ContourPlot.png]

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar cuestion so I am going to post my cuestion and the answer that I got to complete this post. Here is the link [Projection on the xy–plane of the curve of intersection of both surfaces](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/171690/57777)

[image: Quiestion]

[image: REspuesta]

Comment: a) attribution to the author would be on point. b) as well as a copyable code. c) wouldn't it be better to give an example using the equation from this question?