# wolfram mathematica intersection of two surfaces

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration

I use wolfram mathematica.
There is a function of two variables which defines the surface z = f(x,y), the second surface is defined as z = const. How to find the line of intersection of these two surfaces and its projection on XY plane?

Comment: Can you share your code so we have something to work with?

Comment: Have you tried googling for ["mathematica intersection of surfaces"](https://www.google.com/search?q=mathematica+intersection+of+surfaces)?  Have you tried the method in the first google hit?  If yes, what kinds of difficulties did you encounter, or in what way was the solution not sufficient?

Comment: In general there is nothing to say, here is an example that demonstrates how difficult it can be [Can mathematica solve this equation?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17799/can-mathematica-solve-this-equation/17864#17864)

Answer (score 1):

Let `f[x_,y_] := Sin[x + y^2]`.

To plot the intersection of `f[x,y] == z` with `z == 0.5`, use

```
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, z], Mesh -> {{0.5}}]
```

To plot this curve in the plane,

```
ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 0.5, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

Further reading:

- documentation of `Mesh`, `MeshFunction`, `ContourPlot`
- [How can I plot implicit equations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34668/how-can-i-plot-implicit-equations)
- http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/example/HighlightTheIntersectionOfTwoSurfaces.html

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! I can draw 3d graph and see the line of intersection, but how get(extract) the projection on the xy plane in the numerical data (as a function f(x) or FunctionInterpolate(data))? My function f(x, y) is not analytical, its value is calculated numerically.

Comment: @rdm I do not understand the question completely.  Please edit the question and post a sample input (`f` function to work with) and give an example of what sort of output you need (or what you want to do with an output).  If people would only post a *clear enough* question the first time, it would save a lot of time for everyone.