# Projection on the xy–plane of the curve of intersection of both surfaces

Tags: intersection

I am trying to make a projection on the *xy-plane* of the intersection of the surfaces from the functions: `1 + x^2 - y^2`, `3 Log[1 + x^2]`.

[image: Intersection of surfaces]

Thanks.

Comment: Please post copyable code so that users can easily play with it.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher sorry this was my first time posting a question, I´ll do it in the next.

Comment: Mkay... I'll let you off with that... - this time. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Using geometric region functions:

```
RegionPlot@
 ImplicitRegion[
   1 + x^2 - y^2 == 3 Log[1 + x^2],
   {{x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

See also: [Plotting implicitly-defined space curves](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5968/plotting-implicitly-defined-space-curves) for other interesting approaches.

Comment: What do you think about closing this topic as a duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34668/5478 and moving your answer there for completeness?

Comment: @Kuba I agree, your suggestion sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: kuba @MarcoB seems like a good idea, I´ll do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
ContourPlot[1+x^2-y^2==3Log[1+x^2],{x,-1.5,1.5},{y,-1.5,1.5}]
```