# How to plot all the points which satisfy equation/inequality in two variables?

Tags: plotting, inequalities

I am new to Mathematica and I have two questions that I really appreciate if you can help me to solve them.

1) I want to plot all the points (x, y) which satisfy the following equation:

```
 y==11+(1+2x)((11x)/(5+10x))^((3y)/(3y-(5+x)))
```

Where x>0 and y>0.

2) Consider the following inequality where again x>0 and y >0:

```
y>11+(1+2x)((11x)/(5+10x))^((3y)/(3y-(5+x)))
```

I want to figure out range of y that satisfies the inequality given a specific x.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Forgive me, I'm a little confused. If you "want to plot all the points (x, y)" that satisfy some condition, then `x` and `y` are not free variables for which you can "change the value of both x and y dynamically."  Do you mean you want to animate a point that traces along the curve? Or something else?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MichaelE2. You are absolutely right.All I want is to plot the points that satisfy the equation.

Comment: Have you seen [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html)?

Comment: I used it but is showed nothing. Just an empty plot.

Comment: Include the code in the Q. Then we can probably see what went wrong.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34668/how-can-i-plot-implicit-equations

Comment: For the new part 2), consider using [`RegionPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html), or [`Reduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) for solving the inequality for `y` given an `x`.

Comment: Thanks again @MichaelE2. Since I am new I was just trying to find out how can I include the code in Q :D. For the second question I used reduce and the result was y>(11.).  I need an exact value for the range of y and I don't know how can I get that.

Comment: This  [meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) has some advice on formatting code, which may be helpful. -- Isn't `y > 11.` the exact range? (When I use `Reduce`, I get intervals, i.e. inequalities, in terms of [`Root` objects](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects), which are sometimes confusing to new users.)

Comment: ContourPlot can and should plot equations. The following works as expected. Where did you see an empty plot ? ContourPlot[
 y == 11 + (1 + 2 x) ((11 x)/(5 + 10 x))^((3 y)/(3 y - (5 + x))), {x, 
  1, 100}, {y, 1, 100}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
ListPlot[{x,y}/.FindInstance[y==11+(1+2x)((11x)/(5+10x))^((3y)/(3y-(5+x)))&&x>0&&y>0,{x,y},20]]
```

will find and plot 20 pairs of points.

Change that 20 to 200 and it will take longer to give you 200 pairs.

Change that 200 to 2000 and it will take far longer to give you 2000 pairs.

Finding "all" the points seems to be an infinite task.

You can restrict the range doing this

```
ListPlot[{x,y}/.FindInstance[y==11+(1+2x)((11x)/(5+10x))^((3y)/(3y-(5+x)))&&1000>x>0&&y>0,{x,y},3]]
```

It appears if you ask for more points than it can find that it may take a long time to decide that it can't find that many points.

Comment: Thanks Bill. It works perfectly. I think I am gonna need to solve the inequality to find a range for y. May I ask if you have any idea for the second question?

Comment: Your second question appears to puzzle Mathematica, but it appears that if you choose any of those {x,y} values returned from FindInstance then every y value greater than that will satisfy your second question. Thus `N[FindInstance[y==11+(1+2x)((11x)/(5+10x))^((3y)/(3y-(5+x)))&&x>0&&y>0,{x,y}]]` showed me `{{x->4.10529,y->20.}}` and x==4.10529,y==20.01 or y==20.02 or y=30 or y=1000000 all seem to satisfy your `y>11+(1+2x)((11x)/(5+10x))^((3y)/(3y-(5+x)))` condition. Does this work for you?

Comment: Have you tried RegionPlot[
 y > 11 + (1 + 2 x) ((11 x)/(5 + 10 x))^((3 y)/(3 y - (5 + x))), {x, 
  0, 1000}, {y, 0, 1000}] which works well in version 12.0?

Comment: Thanks Bill and "user64494". RegionPlot worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) to find values of `y` for a given value of `x`:

```
yy[x_?NumericQ] := y /. NSolve[y==11+(1+2x)((11x)/(5+10x))^((3y)/(3y-(5+x))), y, Reals]
```

It's a bit slow, but it works:

```
yy[1] //AbsoluteTiming
yy[100] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.002267, {13.0802}}
>
> {0.001798, {33.6105, 234.514}}

You can use [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce) to find the range of `y` values for a given `x` value:

```
rng[x_?NumericQ] := N @ Reduce[y > 11+(1+2x)((11x)/(5+10x))^((3y)/(3y-(5+x))), y, Reals]
```

For example:

```
rng[1]
rng[100]
```

> y > 13.0802
>
> 33.6105 < y < 35. || y > 234.514

If you want to plot the variation of the `y` that satisfies your equation, you could try using [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot). I will use a domain where the function `yy` isn't too slow:

```
Plot[yy[x], {x, 30, 40}]
```

[image]

If you try this with a range with a lower `x`-bound, it will be too slow. In that case, I recommend a technique that I often suggest. Use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue). For your case it would proceed as follows. Create the ODE and find an initial value:

```
eqn = y == 11+(1+2x)((11x)/(5+10x))^((3y)/(3y-(5+x)));
ode = D[eqn /. y->y[x], x];
y1 = yy[1]
```

> {13.0802}

Then, use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) (there is a singularity at the origin which I avoid by starting at [`$MachineEpsilon`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$MachineEpsilon)):

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{ode, y[1] == y1}, y, {x, $MachineEpsilon, 30}];
```

Visualization:

```
Plot[sol[t], {t, 0, 30}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Carl.  That's the answer I was looking for.